# Passing result of resolve into controller with UI-Route

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to learn how to use resolves with UI-Router, and I think there's a piece of information I'm missing, because I can't figure out how to make them work.

I have a state set like this:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('testState', {
            url: '/testRoute',
            controller: 'TestContoller',
            views: {
                "body": { 
                    templateUrl: "testHtml.html" 
                }
             },
            resolve: {
                test:  function(){
                    return {value: "test"};
                 }
            }
        })      
}]);
```

And then I have a controller:

```
app.controller("TestController", ["$scope", "test", function($scope, test) {
    console.log(test);
}]);
```

then I have a testHtml.html partial file that doesn't have anything in at the moment:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
Test content
</div>
```

And that gets loaded into the ui-view in index.html:

```
<div ui-view="body" autoscroll></div>
```

I've been fiddling around with this for an hour or so now and googling around and I can't quite figure out what I should be doing to get the resolve to do something and pass the result into the controller.

Comment: Could you show us the output of "console.log(test);" please ?

Comment: It was "undefined". The problem, as in the accepted solution, was that I had the controller in the wrong place in the state.

Comment: It's also worth saying I had to take ng-controller out of the view, otherwise it ran it twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mention `views` properties on `state` level options, it ignores `templateUrl` & `controller` on that state. It only take controller & `template/templateUrl` from one of view.

**Code**

```
views: {
   "body": { 
      templateUrl: "testHtml.html",
      controller: 'TestContoller' //moved it to named-view level
   }
},
```

Comment: Wow, man, that was simple in the end! Thanks for that. I've been banging my head against the wall with that

Comment: @Simon no problem.. Glad to help you.. Thanks :-)