# ng-click not doing anything in ionic application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

So I'm creating an ionic app with my Uni group and i need to create a tab that will show information from a json file. 
So once I have the page created I can click a link to check it with the dev view as I progress but I need a way to access the page. 
I want this div in this snippet of code to on open this tab/page I will create in the future, currently it should just open a prompt but it doesn't do anything.

```
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
    <ion-list class="eventList">
        <div on-tap="noise()">
        <ion-item>
            <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#">
                <img src="img/ionic.png" class="eImage"/>
                <h2 class="eTitle">CLICK ME!</h2>
                <p class="eDateTime">23/07/17, 12:30pm</p>
                <p class="eDesc">Here there will be a brief description of the event.</p>
            </a>
        </ion-item>
        </div>
```

If we have a look in the app.js file we can see I have linked the controller

```
 .state('tab.home', {
            url: '/home',
            controller: "AppCtrl",
            views: {
                'tab-home': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

if we look in the index.html file we can see I've linked the location of the script

```
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

and if we have a look in the Controller.js we can see the prompt code

```
var App = angular.module("App", ["ionic"]);

App.controller("AppCtrl", ["$scope", "$log", AppCtrl]);

function AppCtrl($scope, $log) {
    $scope.noise = function() {
        alert("Button pressed");
    }
};
```

I'm very new to ionic applications and I already feel beyond stupid for asking this question but how can I achieve this? My google fu is clearly lacking but one needs to know the correct search terms to find the terms they are in fact searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Having `controller: "AppCtrl",` on state level option wouldn't get under consideration(meaning `controller` & `templateUrl` would get ignored if you have `views` option mentioned on state), as you are specifically going to mention `controller` & `templateUrl`'s from `views` section of state.

**Code**

```
views: {
    'tab-home': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
        controller: "AppCtrl" //shifted controller to here
    }
}
```

[**Similar answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36105420/2435473)

Comment: Hello, doing this seems to have broken the Android version of my app and on top of this, it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar is right. It's the corretc way. You'd better start with a Ionic starter project, such as "tabs". Then spend some time looking at app.js and the controllers.

Comment: Actually, it's more ui-router you need to get your hands dirty with. Again, the tabs Starter project is a quick tutorial in itself.